# Discord.py | How to make a discord bot that gives roles when i send a specific message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'give me admin':
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name='role')
        await message.author.add_roles(message.author, role)
```

but im getting this error:

```
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

i swear i typed the name of the role correctly

Comment: "*i swear i typed the name of the role correctly*" - Looks like you did not. Maybe try the ID instead? Also, the `message.author` part in the brackets is redundant as you said `message.author.add_roles`

Comment: _"Maybe try the ID instead?"_ -  i swapped out `role = get(message.guild.roles, name='role')` for `role = get(message.guild.roles, id='900776424208760842')` and im still getting the same error T-T

Comment: Well, is this just for one guild? Maybe you are trying to use the event on a server that does not have the role (Role ID's are unique)

Comment: _"Maybe you are trying to use the event on a server that does not have the role"_- Nope, I ran this on my test bot which in only in my test server which does have that role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, `member.add_roles` doesn't need the `message.author` argument. If you remove that it should work fine.

```py
await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles